# problem with putting things inside a tabbed pane

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, jtabbedpane

I need to put check boxes inside tabbed panes, but they are always on the outside like this
[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/3786/87088242.jpg](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/3786/87088242.jpg)

I want to put the murder check box inside the Input tab. This is what I have in my code

```
import model.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel
{   
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Panel(Prison prison)
    {
        setup();
        build(prison);
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    }

private void build(Prison prison)
{
    JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();

    tab.addTab("Input", null, null, "Input");
    JCheckBox crime = new JCheckBox("murder");
    add(crime);
    tab.addTab("Display", null, null, "Display");
    add(tab);       
}
```

}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why the downvote? Should provide a reason when doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a panel with the button that you want like this.

```
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(crime);
  tab.addTab("Input", null, panel, "Input");
```

That should put the button in the tabpane.

Comment: actually, when I did that, it also appeared in the Display tab. I only want it in the Input tab..

Comment: The display tab will need its own panel. Make sure you are not adding the same panel to both tabs.

Comment: Oh, when I left the panel as null for display, they both had the same thing, but when I created an empty panel and put it in the display tab, it was empty. Thanks a lot :)